# Adding a fav icon in a button using only CSS

Tags: css, favicon

https://codepen.io/danielworton/pen/ZZLEMO

Hello, I'm trying to re-create the button in the codepen linked above and I have an issue adding the stars without changing the script. Also the different colored double border ~ If anyone has any clue to a solution it would be very welcome!

#My solution is as follows:

```css
a {
  border: solid 3px #212121;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,#D3D3D3 0%,#D3D3D3 50%,#e8e8e8 51%);
  color: #212121; 
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pseudo elements](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/) to add more elements:

```css
a {
  border: solid 2px #555;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(0deg, #D3D3D3 0%, #D3D3D3 50%, #e8e8e8 51%);
  color: #555;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px white;
  font-weight: 600;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px #D3D3D3, 0 0 0 8px #555;
}
a:after, a:before {
  content: '★';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}
a:before {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  Checkout
</a>
```

Although, the amount of borders on that button is kind of ridiculous to expect from one element I think.

Edit: you can add multiple borders with boxshadows

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. To implement what you asked for, you will need to use boxshadows as indicated. I have never come across this as job interview question though - who asked you to do this?

Comment: Thank you ~ how did you type in the star symbol?

Comment: it's part of a graduate developer assignment. There are two JS bits and two CSS images to replicate. I haven't had any issues with the others but with this one, I  got stuck on inserting the stars without breaking the button.

Comment: @CristianBurloiu I just copied it from this site https://www.alt-codes.net/star_alt_code.php